# What is the least expensive way to find the two closest numbers surrounding a given value in a list of numbers?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Say we have a list of numbers:

```
{1,3,7,13,19,54}
```

and a single value : `17`

What is the least expensive way to find the closest 2 numbers *surrounding* the value in the list. So in our example, the answer would be `13` and `19`.

Currently, I am using a loop to make 2 lists, one of numbers above and one of numbers below. Then I use something like this:

```
point1 = pointsAbove.Aggregate(Function(x, y) If(Math.Abs(x.X - xVal) < Math.Abs(y.X - xVal), x, y))
point2 = pointsBelow.Aggregate(Function(x, y) If(Math.Abs(x.X - xVal) < Math.Abs(y.X - xVal), x, y))
```

This seems so clunky to me. So I look to you!

Comment: What do you mean by " least expensive"?  Least time? Least memory? Least coding?

Comment: Is you list sorted?

Comment: @DStanley Say a combination between least coding and least memory

Comment: @L.B I hadn't thought of that, but let's say it is. I'll have to go back and investigate to be sure though. Theoretically, the user should have input them in order.

Comment: Get somebody on StackOverflow to write it for you. Can't get cheaper than free.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's what I'm counting on.

Comment: So you want the highest value among values less than X and the lowest value among those values higher than X.  Seems like 2 simple Linq queries.

Comment: @DStanley If your saying I have no alternative but to create two lists, one of points above and one of points below, then I suppose you are right. It's entirely possible that my implementation is already as good as it gets, but as I said, it feels terribly clunky to me and I was hoping to do away with the 2 lists.

Comment: I didn't say two _lists_,  I said two _queries_.  You _could_ do it in one loop but it would be "more coding".

Comment: If they are even sorted, just loop over them once, whats a problem at all?

Comment: How do you wish to handle equality?

Comment: What if X is smaller than the smallest value in the list?  What if X is bigger than the biggest?  What if X is equal to an item in the list?  What if the list is empty?  Are any of those guaranteed not to happen?

Comment: If x is smaller or larger, throw an exception. If x is equal to a value then both both values should be that same value. This is for linear interpolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(){ 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int middle = 6;

var min = numbers.Where(y => y < middle).Max(); // min = 5
var max = numbers.Where(y => y > middle).Min(); // max = 7
```

The code above will work fine for sorted and unsorted lists.

If you can't be certain that you have at least one min and/or one max value, you must do this, otherwise you'll get an Exception:

```
var min = numbers.Where(y => y < middle).DefaultIfEmpty().Max(); 
var max = numbers.Where(y => y > middle).DefaultIfEmpty().Min();
```

And, in the case you are sure 100% of the time that the list is sorted, you can save a bit of performance doing the code below:

```
var min = numbers.LastOrDefault(y => y < middle); 
var max = numbers.FirstOrDefault(y => y > middle);
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: Very nice, this brings the code down to 2 lines from 6 and avoids having to declare 2 lists. I like the use of LINQ! Also, thanks for both scenarios (sorted unsorted)!

Comment: @MatthewGoulart I removed the OrderBy, there was no need for it. The above code will work even for unsorted lists. :)

Comment: I like that it will generate an exception if there is one of the points missing. I'm doing some simple linear interpolation, so it makes sense.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart If you are doing an interpolation, DefaultIfEmpty accepts an int argument to say what you want to be the default value. You can pass in the first one the low side of your interpolation and in the second DefaultIfEmpty you can pass the high side of your interpolation. That's an option too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is sorted, you don't need to iterate the list which would be `O(n)` in time. Using binary search it can be handled in `O(log(n))`.

So my question is: fastest code (plus least memory) vs. shortest code... Your question doesn't say anything about that...

BTW: Handling the corner cases will not be easy..

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 3, 7, 13, 20, 54 };
var numToSearch = 54;
int point1 = int.MinValue, point2 = int.MinValue;

var inx = list.BinarySearch(numToSearch); //<---


if (inx >= 0) //search item is in the list
{
    if (inx == 0)
    {
        point1 = list[0];
        point2 = list[1];
    }
    else if (inx == list.Count - 1)
    {
        point1 = list[inx - 1];
        point2 = list[inx];
    }
    else
    {
        int val1 = list[inx - 1];
        int val2 = list[inx + 1];

        if (Math.Abs(val1 - list[inx]) < Math.Abs(list[inx] - val2))
        {
            point1 = list[inx - 1];
            point2 = list[inx];
        }else
        {
            point1 = list[inx];
            point2 = list[inx+1];
        }
    }
}
else {
    point1 = list[~inx - 1];
    point2 = list[~inx];
}
```

PS: **Least time? Least memory? Least Code? Hard to achieve(if not impossible) at the same time. Seems like OP will pick up a random answer :)**

PS2: I wouldn't expect OP would *accept* this answer after reading previous note :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify what happens if your single value (17) has no lower of higher value, I will let them default to NULL here.

```
int number = 17; 
int? lower = points.LastOrDefault(x => x < number);
int? upper = points.FirstOrDefault(x => x > number);
```

or in one line, allthough this is uglier imo

```
Tuple<int?, int?> closestNumbers = new Tuple<int?, int?>(points.LastOrDefault(x => x < number), points.FirstOrDefault(x => x > number));
```